# How can I debug a timeout in SQL query triggered by action in another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, azure, concurrency

I'm facing some "impossible behavior" situation and I need to somehow debug it.

I have two threads, A and B. Thread B class has these three variables:

```
public class ThreadBClass() {
    private static bool shouldStop = false;
    private static objects shouldStopLock = new object();
    public static void SetShouldStop()
    {
        lock( shouldStopLock ) {
           shouldStop = true;
        } 
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        while( true ) {
            lock( shouldStopLock ) {
                if( shouldStop ) {
                   break;
                }
            }
            doStuff(); << this thing queries SQL Azure database
        }
    }
}
```

Thread A has this

```
var bClass = new threadBClass();
var controlledThread = new Thread( bClass.Run );
```

thread B runs `Run()` with an infinite loop periodically querying SQL Azure database.

Now these two threads run inside Windows Azure web role and when role is being stopped the following happens. Role `OnStop()` is run in thread A and does this:

```
ThreadBClass.SetShouldStop();
const int count = 20;
for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
   if( controlledThread.IsAlive ) {
       break;
   }
   Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
}
```

If thread B happens not to be querying the database when the flag is being set everything exits cleanly. But something like 40% of the time the SQL database query fails with the exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
the operation or the server is not responding.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
//my code of Run() here
```

I've tried outputting the `ThreadState` of each thread. Thread B state is `Running`, so it was definitely not aborted.

So whole situation to me looks insane - one thread acquires a lock for a while and then polls the other thread for `IsAlive` and exactly at that time the SQL query times out in another thread. And this is reproducible *once in a while*.

How do I debug this? Are there any events, global variables, whatever else that .NET runtime exposes and that I could use to find what's actually going on?

Comment: What is it that initiates "role is being stopped"? It looks to me like this is nothing to do with the lock / check, but is instead related to some other things that are happening; maybe the sub-system itself is shutting down external connections, because *it knows the role is shutting down*. Setting a value inside a lock will not cause a TDS error. Things that might cause a TDS error include: the database server being busy; the database server shutting itself down; the network connection being severed.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Azure runtime calls `OnStop()` as part of a much larger role "stop" sequence.

Comment: yeah, I figured; but the short of this is: the error you are seeing has *nothing whatsoever* to do with your lock/bool; it is erroring *because it is being shut down*.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: So your guess is that the problem arises outside of the program. Well, that makes sense. Could you please craft some minimalistic answer from your first comment?